# How to add values to list without deleting already exsists

Tags: python

so as i have written in title i have problem with 2 things, mainly i want to add values in to a list and dont delete already existing, but i cant figure out how to do it, for now when im writing something everything old gets deleted. My second problem is that i cant make condition to use upper letter T and lower t, can anyone help me? here is the code:

```
import pickle



    zadania = []
    
    a = input("Do you want to add value? T/N")
    while True:
        if a == 'T':
            zadania.append(str(input('Write what you want to add: ')))
            a = input("Do you want add something else? T/N")
    
        elif a == 'N':
            break
        else:
            while a not in 'TN':
                print("Wrong value")
                a = input("Do you want add something else? T/N")
    
    
    with open('zad', 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(zadania, fp)
```

Comment: In the code you have provided you never load the contents of the file.

Comment: What do you mean "don't delete already existing"? Do you mean that the file you dump to has items that you want to keep? If so, you should read it first. Then you will have those items.

Comment: @CodeMonkey For single letter strings, both of these will have the same behavior.

Comment: Yea i meant to keep the items, sorry for my weak explanation but my english is not too good but as i can see, you guys helped me already :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: Open the file for appending (`a`) instead of overwriting with `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zadania = []
```

This always starts with an empty list. If you don't want that, then you should do something different. For example, you could check if the file you wrote before already exists. If it does, load it before getting more items.

Answer (score 0):

For lower and upper case you could use `if` check as follows:

```py
if a.lower()=="t":
    pass
```

OR

```py
if a.upper()=="T":
    pass
```

Regarding list, your list is adding new element in existing list.
But if you are loading your list from pickle then you should first initialize `zadania` to pickle value and not directly `[]` empty. If pickle is not having any value then assign `[]` else pickle value.